# display text in product view page if "Tier prices" are availble

Tags: tierprice

we have to display some text in product view page under  tag

if "tier prices" are available , than we want to dispaly that text

"tier prices are available"

or we have to dispalay the text

"tier prices are not available "

we are using this code : http://pastebin.com/Ye5i2TgQ = > app/design/frontend/default/theme_name/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml for displaying tier prices

please guide me about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
//$product is your current product 
if($_product->getTierPrice()) {
   echo "available";
}
else{
  echo "not available";
}
```

Source [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497533/check-if-product-has-tier-pricing)

Comment: getting this error : : Call to a member function getTierPrice() on a non-object in when i added in view.phtml

Comment: please check line number 259 here : http://pastebin.com/8AQSMScY  = > view.phtml

Comment: replace `$product` with `$_product`

Comment: thanks , instead of text if i want to add one complete <div> tag,  means echo " <div class="a"> availble </div>"


what i have to replce with the text?

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 yes you can replace anything(content) in that condition.

Comment: as you said, i am using this code http://pastebin.com/pSSqS5gC 

but the css part is not working , means its not dipalying ".coupontooltip" class 

i added those css to dispaly tooltip. you can see the tooltip in this link 

http://hotwheelstoys.in/mobileapp2/peacock-bebe-blocks-set-no-7.html

see next to "cash on delivery"  = > "?" button is tooltip

tooltip is not displaying. please help me.

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 the tooltip is displaying. Any other issue

Comment: before tooltip was displaying from normal html code. please check the link now. i used your code

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 Check this http://pastebin.com/pv2XVxrY , I have added class="Delivery_hover_details" to div and "?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26605/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-2-and-meenakshi-sundaram-r).